# DeleteSubString in Java

Tags: java

I have written my own deleteSubString method as i'm experimenting creating all the java functions. However i'm having issues with the output it produces. Here is my code:

```
        //deleteSubString
    String subString = "ON";
    String delString = "PONY";
    String emp = "";
    int delIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<delString.length()-1; i++){
        if(delString.contains(subString)){
            //do nothing
            //read the rest of the string to confirm it contains
            for(int j=delIndex; j<delString.length()-1; j++){
                if(delString.contains(subString)){
                    //do nothing
                }
                else{
                    emp += delString.charAt(j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Delete SubString");
        System.out.println(emp);
    }
```

What I expect to happen is the string to print out as "PY" but instead it chooses not to print anything at all. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've edited the placement of code so that it's now in the if statement and it prints however it loops the output like so: "PONYPONYPONY"

Answer (score 1):

`if(delString.contains(subString)){` is always true so `emp` is never set to a new `String`.

Comment: You were quicker, but you should clarify, this statement occurs 2 times.

Comment: I think I must have been coding in my sleep to miss something so obvious!! It's working now but yet it prints PONPONPON why is it looping like that? @his

Comment: I didn't look into the algorithm in depth and I will not. Use the built-in methods if you want to do the job; if you don't want to use them then the whole point is to find and fix errors yourself.

Answer (score 1):

PONY contains ON and `delString.length()-1` won't consider the last character,so your else part would not run.

Instead simply do

```
if(delString.contains(subString))
{
    int delSize=subString.length();
    int index1=delString.indexOf(subString);
    int index2=index1+delSize;
    return delString.substring(0,index1)+""+delString.substring(index2+1);
}
else return delString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
(delString.contains(subString))
```

This statement will always be true with the strings you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s : delString.split(subString)) {
    emp += s;
}
```

is this what you want?

Comment: well i'm trying to avoid using in built functions like split() and indexOf. Is there a way to delete a selected substring from the string with just a loop instead of java functions?

Comment: so, this is something like a homework? search about KMP algorithm which is a substring quick search algorithm. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String subString = "ONY";
    String delString = "PONY";
    String emp = "";
    StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder(subString);
    StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder(delString);
    for(int i=0;i<sb2.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sb1.length();j++)
        {
        if(sb2.charAt(i)==sb1.charAt(j))
        {
            sb2.deleteCharAt(i);
        }

        }

    }
    emp=sb2.toString();
    System.out.println(emp);
```

Sorry!!I have revamped the code but looks like its going to work fine...the problem with the string class is its immutability...The cod which you wrote doesnt give the require output...if it gives it can delete only first character i.e only O in your case Y is not getting deleted so i converted into StringBuffer class and wrote that..Happy Coding!